# How can create calculated field in Python similar to excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to migrate pivot tables from Excel to python, for using visualizations and others. I use two calculated fields in excel, so I want to know if is possible using similar idea with Pandas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Adding some code may encourage people to point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you know python a day or two exploring the pandas docs and popular question under pandas tag might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your data looks like, but this definitely possible with pandas.

Here's an example:

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [17, 23, 4, 27],
                    'name': ['John', 'Mark', 'Alice', 'Alice']})
```

**Output1**

```
    age name
0   17  John
1   23  Mark
2   4   Alice
3   27  Alice
```

Create calculated field with `np.where` method
Logic behind this method:
`np.where(condition, true value, false value)`
Find more [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['adult_indicator'] = np.where(df.age >= 18, 1, 0)
```

**Output2**

```
    age name    adult_indicator
0   17  John    0
1   23  Mark    1
2   4   Alice   0
3   27  Alice   1
```

Apply `pivot` method from the `pandas` module

```
df.pivot(index='name', columns='age', values='adult_indicator')
```

**Output3**

```
    age 4   17  23  27
name                
Alice   0.0 NaN NaN 1.0
John    NaN 0.0 NaN NaN
Mark    NaN NaN 1.0 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks you Erfan, I going to check your example with my code.

Comment: @VictoriaUbaldo Good luck! If the answer helped you, please flag it as _answer_ so others with a similar question can be helped as well.